# socket [10053] error in whatsAPI PHP sending message

Tags: php, whatsapi

I'm using whatsapp api PHP Library : [Chat API](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API)

And I got this error when I'm trying to send message :

> "socket_write(): unable to write to socket [10053]: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

How to solve it?

Comment: it's a network problem. maybe you have an antivirus/firewall that's blocking your connection.